# run multiple mysql pods in kubernetes

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I would like to create a kubernetes cluster to deploy mysql databases, like a mysql farm. These databases should be accessible from internet.

All databases on the same node will have the port 3306 listening, the kube-proxy or the DNS addon could redirect each request to an specific container?

I would like to create url's like myDB1.example.com:3306, myDB2.example.com:3306 that goes to an specific container.

I'm deploying this environment in AWS.

It's possible to create this cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Starting point would be a (customized) [MySQL Docker image](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/4797ba77f07cb8ccd650a888b072f1d9de89f439/5.5/Dockerfile) with [EBS backed volumes](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/volumes.html#awselasticblockstore) and you'd be using it in an [Replication Controller](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/replication-controller.html) to handle failover. On top of that you would have a [Service](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/services.html) that provides a stable and routable interface to the outside world. Optionally, put an [AWS Elastic Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) in front of it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now, my doubts are related in the DNS resolution. The cluster has one public IP and one port (3306) to access into Mysql. How I redirect each request (myDB1.example.com:3306) in a particular container? I've investigated, maybe one solution is implement a reverse-proxy like Nginx to redirect each request. Also, I've seen a service called http://consul.io that offers service discovery. It could be a solution?

Comment: How about you upvote and/or mark the answer as correct so that people who run into the same question understand it as well? 

Yes, Consul is an option, see also http://programmableinfrastructure.com/ for more …

Comment: Speaking from the future, your answer didn't really address his question - which is what I'm looking into at the moment; how do you resolve different DNS names via an Ingress controller (or something similar), to where you can have multiple hosts that point to a single service in Kubernetes. Your answer was a general, "This is the right way to install a MySQL farm" answer.